# How to generate change log file in liquibase using Java

Tags: java, liquibase

I want to generate a change log XML file in liquibase using Java, which stores the information of two databases difference.

My code is:

```
Database database=CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(MySQLConnection.class.getClassLoader(), 
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "admin", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "", null,false,false,null,null,null,null);

        Database database2=CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(MySQLConnection.class.getClassLoader(), 
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzashop", "root", "admin", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "", null,false,false,null,null,null,null);
      CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog("changelog.xml", database2, database,new DiffOutputControl(),null,null);
```

But it generates a blank `changelog.xml` file.

Comment: Right now, there is a typo in the script above that sends the output to 'chagelog.xml' rather than 'changelog.xml', but that could be just a typo here.

Comment: I have changed my code but still the result is same

Comment: could you set logLevel=DEBUG in your liquibase properties file and then attach the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my question.use liquibase 2.0.3 version.

Code is:

```
Database database=CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(MySQLConnection.class.getClassLoader(), 
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal", "root", "admin", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
                null,null,null);

        Database database2=CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(MySQLConnection.class.getClassLoader(), 
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/llportal", "root", "admin", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                null,null,null);
    CommandLineUtils.doDiffToChangeLog("changeLogFile.xml",database, database2)
```

;